# In SQL Server do I have to use exec sp_addrolemember to grant a role to a user?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server do I have to use exec sp_addrolemember to grant a role to a user ?

i.e. It seems I have to use a command like:

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'My_Role1', 'DOMAIN\User1'
```

It doesn't seem I can use this type of command or anything like this? :

```
GRANT My_Role1 to DOMAIN\User1
```

Comment: Did you consider looking at the documentation for `sp_addrolemember`? Perhaps follow the notes about it's future obsolescence and what it should be replaced with?

Comment: No mention of obsolescence or equivalent preferred alternative ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: How do *you* read "This feature **will be removed** in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. **Use ALTER ROLE instead.**"?

Comment: Ah - yeah - in blue - I see it now ! ..  thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In SQL Server do I have to use exec sp_addrolemember to grant a role to a user ?

No. In fact you should not use it at all per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **Important**
>
> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
> Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
> modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER ROLE
> instead.

The equivalent ALTER ROLE statement is:

```
ALTER ROLE My_Role1
    ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\User1];
```

Comment: Think the other way around ...  Think Oracle is different ..  grant role to user ..   rather than this way around.

Comment: @AllanF, it's common to see different syntax in different RDBMS products, especially for statements beyond the entry level ISO SQL standard and in databases that have been around for a while.